# Real-time SQL syntax highlighting in HTML5

Tags: html, css, textarea, syntax-highlighting

I want to use a `<textarea>` tag or an alternative written in JavaScript, that highlights my SQL statements as I write them (effectively the same as phpMyAdmin's SQL section where you can manually write queries.)

Please tell me that this is possible without using HUGE libraries and can be easily customizable. If so, which library should I be using and how?

Comment: textareas cannot be formatted except gross font/size changes. you can't embed spans/font tags to change their appearance.

Comment: Use JQuery to format the text in the textarea as a text somewhere in a div.

Comment: do you count [codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) to huge library?

Comment: I do not understand why it is classified as "not a real question," after all, this question has been viewed more than 4,000 times ...

Comment: @simhumileco Vote to reopen.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://codemirror.net/

I think I found what I wanted. Though this looks like a big library, this will do the trick. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Closed as "not a real question" yet it was very helpful to me. You gotta love the quality control folk here...Not

Comment: https://github.com/codemirror/codemirror

Comment: @ChadD Vote to re-open.  This is the first Google result.